# How can I access Excel.RequestContext while in Office.onReady()?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I want to control some aspects of my Excel add-in (written in TypeScript) UI based on custom properties of the Excel document. For this, I need to access Excel.RequestContext while I'm in the Office.onReady() method. Is that possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just chain the two calls?  I.e.:

In TypeScript:

```
(async () => {
    await Office.onReady();
    await Excel.run(async context => {
        <...>
    });
})()
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
Office.onReady().then(function() {
    return Excel.run(function(context) {
        <...>
    }); 
})
```